# Dynamic delimiter for number in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

Based upon the below delimiters how to display the number in angular js

Example of formatting are:

```
Format                                  Input                                 Output
#########                               100000000                             100000000
###,###,###                             100                                   100
###,###,###                             10000                                 10,000
###,###,###                             100000                                100,000
###,###,###                             1000000                               1,000,000
###,###,###                             100000000                             100,000,000
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="font:15px Verdana;" ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-app>
        <p>
            <label>Enter a number</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="bid" />
        </p>

        <p> {{ bid | PointsFormater }} </p>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('PointsFormater', function() {
    return function(x) {
        var delimiter = "###,##,###,#0.00";
        var decArr=delimiter.split(",");
        if(decArr.length>1){
            for(var i=0; i< decArr.length; i++){
                console.log(decArr[i]);             
                console.log(decArr[i].length);              
            }
        }   
        return x;
    };
});
</script>
</html>
```

Based on the delimiter value result should be like this **123,45,6789,10.00**

Example :- [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3sq74f4r/1/)

Comment: did you tried number filter?

Comment: @ManikandanVelayutham Yes I tried, but need custom delimiter based on user configuration.

Comment: Answer :- http://jsfiddle.net/nuqzy6tu/1/